# Codeigniter 3.0 , You did not select a file to upload

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, file-upload, routes

I have followed all the answers available on internet related to this topic, after 4 hours of searching and trying still no success..

Error thrown is 
**You did not select a file to upload.**

---

**EDIT**

Tried using `$_FILES` method too.

---

I tried `if($this->input->post('userfile')!==null)`

to check whether image is being passed to controller or not and it turns out it doesn't as the if condition was not executed.

I have followed this guide to upload files on server.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=file%20upload

don't know what the issue is.

you can find the code in the above link.

my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

I tried all the suggestions you guys provided.

Yeah it was my mistake to check the image via $_POST instead of $_FILES

But still the issue is same. I am posting the code I use and the URL which you can check too.

Any help would really be appreciated thankyou.

**ImageUploadController.php**

```
<?php

 class ImageUploadController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('image-upload/upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    public function store($workType)
    {


            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('imageFile'))
            {
                if(isset($_FILES['imageFile']))  
                    echo "isset";

                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('image-upload/upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('image-upload/upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
}
?>
```

**upload_form.php**

https://gist.github.com/VickySalunkhe/1dc66ec6d3af8cf097a5c01b5009c804

**upload_result.php**

https://gist.github.com/VickySalunkhe/691626e4fe6dd8a8b3896d210e4b22b9

Route set for the request

```
$route['upload'] = 'ImageUploadController';
//stores the images on server
$route['store/(:any)'] = 'ImageUploadController/store/$1';
```

you can ignore the part for second route , its for some other logic part which will be implemented later on.

Comment: Files are stored in the `$_FILES` array not the `$_POST` array which `$this->input->post()` accesses. I find it difficult to believe that you followed the docs you listed and came up with this solution not that I'm denying something is wrong. Why don't you post relevant sections of your view/model/controller to your last attempt so we can see where it is going wrong? make sure your form is a multipart form as well!

Comment: Hi @Alex I tried using the $FILES method still it is not working, I have edited my question [included the code I am using ] please go through it. Thankyou

Comment: you are posting to `store/user` not `ImageUploadController/store` do you have routes set-up? or is this a mistake?

Comment: I have a route set for it.,  I have added my routes too now in my question.

Comment: at the very beginning of your `store` function can you provide me with a `print_r($_FILES); exit;`

Comment: Hi @Ailex I added the code at the starting of `store` function. after submitting the form I am getting an output as `Array ( )`, you can test the code here https://www.writco.in/upload     , I have removed `exit;` from the code

Comment: i'm sorry i just don't understand what could be the problem. if the file was too big for the server, or if there was another error the files array should atleast be populated and have an error flag set. this is like... there is no file at all, but you have the correct form enctype. does this issue persist in a local environment?

Comment: I have not tested on local environment. I am now using base64 encode to store the file on server. Don't know what's the issue with default file uploader of codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file in CodeIgniter 3 I recommend you use the File Uploading class.

You will find the link here: [Uploading files in CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

For what I see, is what you used above.

The documentation says you have to first load the upload library, with some configuration settings (see docs):

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config)
```

And then the method that does the actual upload (based on config params) is this:

```
$this->upload->do_upload('<your-file-name>');
```

Notice where it says,  there you have to use the name of the file you are uploading via HTML. The file itself is not found on a POST array, but in the FILES array, everytime you are uploading a file using the HTML `<input type="file">` element.

Comment: Hi @MarkSkayff I am already using the exact method mentioned the CodeIgniter posts. still the issue is same, I have edited my question so you can have a look at the code which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Try Blow Code

1) HTML:

```
<form action="/profile_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

2) PHP file:

```
if($_FILES['file']['name']!='')  {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/admin/big';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '10240';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        // ERROR
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    } 
    else {
        // SUCCESS
        $file_name = $this->upload->file_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check form enctype attribute e.g
2. check $_FILES variable empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('updateFunctionName');?>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="artworkpath">Artwork</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="artworkpath" name="artworkpath" value="<?php echo $artworkpath; ?>">
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
function updateFunctionName(){
    $artworkpath = $this->input->post('artworkpath');

    $CheckFileName = true;
    if ($_FILES['artworkpath']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['artworkpath']['error'] == 0)
    {
    $CheckFileName = false;
    }
    else
    {
    $filename2 = 'Artwork_'.rand(0,999999);

    if( ! is_dir('uploads') ){mkdir('uploads',0777,TRUE); };      
    $path='uploads/';        
    $imgtmpname=$_FILES['artworkpath']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES["artworkpath"]["name"];
    $ext = end((explode(".", $name)));
    $fullpath= $path .$filename2.'.'.$ext;
    $filename = $filename2;
    move_uploaded_file($imgtmpname,$fullpath);
    }
```

In DB save this variable data in column:

```
    $Info = array();
    if ($ext <> '')
    {
    $Info = array('artworkpath'=>$fullpath, //other fields);
    }
    else
    {
    $Info = array(//other fields);
    }
    $this->user_model->updateRecord($Info, $Id);
}
```

Model:

```
function updateRecord($Info, $Id)
{
    $this->db->where('Id', $Id);
    $this->db->update('tablename', $Info);
}
```